# Insert div id into script

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I have a script where clicking on a particular div (eg id=packtoa) will (amongst other things) .addclass('show') to listview items with a class which matches the id of the div clicked.

Which works great, but then I'll want the next div (id=packfhag) to do the same thing, and then the next one. So I've got the same script many times in my js with just the id & class name changed.

I'm sure there's a stupidly obvious way to automate this so that any div with an id starting with "pack" will trigger this script, pull the div id, and insert it into the script where  the name of the class is called.

And I'm sure I'm close with trying to adapt this script:

```
$("div[id^=pack]").each(function() {
    var match = this.id.match(/\w+$/)[0];
    $(this).addClass('show');
});
```

But I just can't crack it. Either something above is wrong, or I'm inserting it into the wrong place in the script:

```
// Tears of Ameratsu menu functions
    $(document).bind('pageinit', function() {
// When link is clicked
  $('#packtoa').click(function() {
// collapse the expansions menu
     $("#expansionsmenu").click();
// hide everything except this expansion
    $(".hidden").removeClass('show');
    $(".packtoa").addClass('show');
// clear the search, and trigger a blank search
   $('input[data-type="search"]').val('');
    $('input[data-type="search"]').trigger("keyup");
    });
});
```

What am I missing?

Comment: why not make the click action on a class rather than an ID, then every new created div has the same class?

Answer (score 0):

```
// for selecting div which starts with pack
// not recommended
$("div[id^='pack']");
```

The best option is to use `class` attribute, add class attribute to all those `div`, and then

```
$('.commonClass').addClass('show');
```

For Example :

```js
// this is for testing
// say you click  
$('#test').on('click',function(){
  $('.testclass').addClass('show');
});
```

```css
.testclass{
display:none;
}
.show {
  display:block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="testclass">div1</div>
<div class="testclass">div2</div>
<div class="testclass">div3</div>

<input type='button' value='Click me to view div' id='test' />
```

Comment: I'm a bit confused by the answer. It looks like your code does the same as mine, click on id: test, and it'll affect class: testclass. But then when you need to do the same with a different set of id / class, won't you need to type out the same script but with test1 / testclass1, and then type it again with test3 etc etc.

Comment: for multiple classes you can select like this : `$('.class1, .class2, .class3')`

Comment: If I run $(test').. to addclass ('show') to $('.class1, .class2 etc), then #test will add 'show' to all of them. Whereas I need #test1 to addclass to .test1, and #test2 to addclass to .test2 etc